# What does "for many definitional purposes" mean here?

Tags: meaning

Society is ***for many definitional purposes*** political society? The passage is not easy at all. Most of all, the sentence including the expression evades me. What does it mean?

> The modern concept of law and the modern sociological concept of
> society have common origins in the composite idea of the nation state
> brought to full realization in the revolutionary period of the late
> eighteenth century(Woolf 1991). In the shadow of this idea, law and
> society are almost mutually defining. Society is ***for many
> definitional purposes*** *political* society; that is, a territorially
> defined arena of social interaction regulated by a specific political
> system (for example, British society; French society). Society is,
> thus, significantly delimited by the jurisdictional reach of legal
> systems(cf. Lacey 1998: 120). This, however, undermines the idea that
> law is in some sense a product or expression of society. One might put
> matters the other way around: (political) society is a product of
> law(Fitzpatrick 1995). If the unity of society is fragmented, so too
> is that of law as a social phenomenon.

[Law, Culture and Society: Legal Ideas in the Mirror of Social Theory](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=OUg4DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT99&lpg=PT99&dq=Society%20is%20for%20many%20definitional%20purposes%20political%20society;%20that%20is,%20a%20territorially%20defined%20arena%20of%20social%20interaction%20regulated%20by%20a%20specific%20political%20system&source=bl&ots=wA6vUGFyh4&sig=ACfU3U11KfUQm92U9jy-ttOB49Ch3XK9Lg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiu6ovKoej2AhWQqFYBHUcdA7EQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=Society%20is%20for%20many%20definitional%20purposes%20political%20society%3B%20that%20is%2C%20a%20territorially%20defined%20arena%20of%20social%20interaction%20regulated%20by%20a%20specific%20political%20system&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

There are several definitions/terms using the word 'society', in many of those definitions, it is a 'political society'.

And yes, this is not an easy passage, but that's true for most scientific books. Popular science is a separate genre after all ...

Answer (score 1):

'Definitional' is not in most dictionaries but, as this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=definitional&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdefinitional%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdefinitional%3B%2Cc0) shows, its usage rose steadily from 1940 to 1980, and since then it has remained stable. Most of the usages are in academic publications.

If you can't find a word in a dictionary, it's worth checking a list of [prefixes and suffixes](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/list-of-suffixes-and-suffix-examples.html) to see whether it is understandable as a variant of a dictionary word. In this case, the suffix **-al** means 'concerning'.

What this sentence means is:

> 'Society' can, for many purposes, be defined as 'political society'.